# http get response gives unexpected output

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm having two observables, both fetching data from REST interface. The first method returns two records as expected.

```
{id: "1", value: "One-Way"}
{id: "3", value: "Return/Multiple"}
```

The second method's output includes first method's result as well (7+2).

```
{id: "1", value: "One-Way"}
{id: "3", value: "Return/Multiple"}
{id: "2", value: "Short Term - Training"}
{id: "3", value: "Short Term - Business Meeting"}
{id: "4", value: "Short Term - Due Diligence"}
{id: "8", value: "Other Specify"}
{id: "20", value: "Domestic - Deputation"}
{id: "28", value: "STTA"}
{id: "30", value: "LTTA"}
```

As you can see from the methods below, they're independent and not storing or performing any calculations, just logging after fetching data.

```
getOfficeLocation(): Observable<object>{
return this.http.get<object>("http://localhost:8086/travel/getjourneylist")
.pipe(tap((response: Response) => {console.log(response)}))}

getPurposeOfTravelDom(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get<object>("http://localhost:8086/travel/getcitytravelpurposelist")
.pipe(tap((response: Response) => {console.log(response)}))}
```

Because both results have id/value combination, will that cause any glitch while fetching data? Or am I doing anything wrong? If I directly fetch the URL from browser, I can see proper result, first URL returns 2 records and second returns 7 records.

Appreciate your help.

[Travel Purpose JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpJcF.png)

Comment: `will that cause any glitch while fetching data?` <= no, why would it?

Comment: But the data is getting overlapped, I cannot find a reason for the overlap.

Comment: Are you sure the data does not contain first two items when you GET this url in a browser window? http://localhost:8086/travel/getcitytravelpurposelist

Comment: The **shown code** is fine, there is nothing wrong with that. Your issue is either what you are doing with the response or something server side that compiles and sends the response.

Comment: Yes, the localhost JSON response doesn't have the first two entries. Screenshot attached . As you can see, the response is printed straight out without any modifications.